# How to Integrate Identity with Existing MVC App and Migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an application that contains as best SoC as I can muster and my business entities are in my Core.Entities project.  I have a Core.Data project that houses my DbContext(s) and enable migrations.  I have a services project (Core.Services) in which all of my business logic occurs.  In an MVC project, I have implemented Identity.  Without having two separate migration scripts as well as having to add a reference to the Data project inside the MVC project, how on earth do I include Identity in my migration (which Identity *should* never change) script if it's not in the MVC project where Identity lives?

Comment: You can add the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework NuGet package in your Data and Entities project, which will give those projects access to the `IdentityDbContext` and `IdentityUser` classes. You should be able to copy most of the Identity-related code in the MVC project to your Services or Data project.

Comment: I could, but should I?  I was under the impression that Identity is for the web only and by moving it, it's the assumption that it would be reused elsewhere.  I'm having trouble grasping the concept and purpose of Identity.  It's almost as if it's created as a "starter kit" of authentication/authorization and doesn't provide a flexible design so that it can be implemented in an enterprise architecture.

Comment: I understand your concern completely; I had the same impression before. But nowadays I don't see Identity being strongly tied to the web anymore. I also believe that moving a module somewhere else is a good idea for clarity / maintainability purposes, even if there is no reuse scenario. I agree that it's a starter kit and that is why it was included in the web project template, so that developers can get up and running quickly.

Comment: But it's possible to treat it just like any other business-related service that might live somewhere in your business logic or infrastructure layer. (I am doing something similar in my own projects.) Sorry for the long comments!

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  They make sense and align with my feelings as well.  I will move as much Identity to a new security class library and see how it goes.